AWS IoT File Stream from S3 - Response not in order and PacketType=7b
The coreMQTT library is throwing an error with the message:
Unexpected packet type from server: PacketType=7b

This indicates that the client has received a packet from the server that it does not recognize or expect in the current state. According to the MQTT specification, "7b" does not correspond to any standard packet type, indicating a potential issue with packet corruption or incorrect handling.
I have ensured that the packet types being sent and received align with expected MQTT communication patterns. Based on AWS Documentation
Here are the logs from my device which is

ESP32 on framework ESP-IDF v4.4.8 (Commit a9d0f221)
coreMQTT (LTS 202406.01 Commit 4f11b8ca).

Documentation says on step GetStream request :

5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 to receive all data blocks. You must repeat these steps if the amount of data requested is larger than 128 KB. You must program your device to use multiple GetStream requests to receive all of the data requested.

However, these logs indicate that the stream can start from a different position than requested in the payload. For instance, the requested offset was 0 ["o":0], but the received offset was 1 ["i":1]. When the request was made again for offset 0 ["o":0], the response was with offset 2 ["i":2]. The logic requires the incoming packets to arrive in order, but this issue only appears in this example. The longest error-free communication I managed, with valid packets in order, was 18 out of the 847 packets expected.
@edit also response clientToken ["c"] is always as the first payload send, never changes.
_MQTT[PUBSUB]: [627][_mqtt_subscribe] Subscription to topic [$aws/things/<serialNumber>/jobs/get/accepted]:[38] with QoS: [0]
_MQTT[PUBSUB]: [627][_mqtt_subscribe] Subscription to topic [$aws/things/<serialNumber>/jobs/get/rejected]:[38] with QoS: [0]
_MQTT[PUBSUB]: [684][_mqtt_publish] Publishing to topic :: 
[$aws/things/<serialNumber>/jobs/get][29]. payload :: {"clientToken":"HNezYuG6EVzNjJ6PAQZOxdGSC3NIw7f"}][49].
_MQTT[PUBSUB]: [400][_mqtt_handle_deserialized_info] Message from Topic: [$aws/things/<serialNumber>/jobs/get/accepted][38] Payload [246] {"clientToken":"HNezYuG6EVzNjJ6PAQZOxdGSC3NIw7f","timestamp":1721990707,"inProgressJobs":[{"jobId":"<AFR_OTA>","queuedAt":1721303991,"lastUpdatedAt":1721376545,"startedAt":1721304351,"executionNumber":1,"versionNumber":8}],"queuedJobs":[]}

_MQTT[PUBSUB]: [627][_mqtt_subscribe] Subscription to topic [$aws/things/<serialNumber>/jobs/<AFR_OTA>/get/accepted]:[55] with QoS: [0]
_MQTT[PUBSUB]: [627][_mqtt_subscribe] Subscription to topic [$aws/things/<serialNumber>/jobs/<AFR_OTA>/get/rejected]:[55] with QoS: [0]
_MQTT[PUBSUB]: [684][_mqtt_publish] Publishing to topic :: 
[$aws/things/<serialNumber>/jobs/<AFR_OTA>/get][46]. payload :: [{"jobId":"<AFR_OTA>","thingName":"<serialNumber>","includeJobDocument":true,"clientToken":"B4aXiEgw0ddWcQtdvbZ02Q7JonKxeQm"}][125].
_MQTT[PUBSUB]: [400][_mqtt_handle_deserialized_info] Message from Topic: 
[$aws/things/<serialNumber>/jobs/<AFR_OTA>/get/accepted][55] Payload [559] {"clientToken":"B4aXiEgw0ddWcQtdvbZ02Q7JonKxeQm","timestamp":1721990708,"execution":{"jobId":"<AFR_OTA>","status":"IN_PROGRESS","queuedAt":1721303991,"startedAt":1721304351,"lastUpdatedAt":1721376545,"versionNumber":8,"executionNumber":1,"jobDocument":{"afr_ota":{"protocols":["MQTT"],"streamname":"<AFR_OTA_STREAMNAME>","files":[{"filepath":"/","filesize":3466990,"fileid":0,"certfile":"<KEY>","sig-sha256-ecdsa":"<SIG>"}]}}}}

_MQTT[PUBSUB]: [627][_mqtt_subscribe] Subscription to topic [$aws/things/<serialNumber>/streams/<AFR_OTA_STREAMNAME>/rejected/json]:[87] with QoS: [0]
_MQTT[PUBSUB]: [627][_mqtt_subscribe] Subscription to topic [$aws/things/<serialNumber>/streams/<AFR_OTA_STREAMNAME>/description/json]:[90] with QoS: [0]
_MQTT[PUBSUB]: [627][_mqtt_subscribe] Subscription to topic [$aws/things/<serialNumber>/streams/<AFR_OTA_STREAMNAME>/data/json]:[83] with QoS: [0]
_MQTT[PUBSUB]: [684][_mqtt_publish] Publishing to topic :: 
[$aws/things/<serialNumber>/streams/<AFR_OTA_STREAMNAME>/describe/json][87]. payload :: [{"c":"zIwS0VcrhdRNf5jkQPGm9p9qnQs97oX"}][39].
_MQTT[PUBSUB]: [400][_mqtt_handle_deserialized_info] Message from Topic: [$aws/things/<serialNumber>/streams/<AFR_OTA_STREAMNAME>/description/json][90] Payload [107] {"c":"zIwS0VcrhdRNf5jkQPGm9p9qnQs97oX","s":1,"d":"Stream for OTAUpdate","r":[{"f":0,"z":3466990}]}

_PART[firmware]: Starting OTA Update
_PART[firmware]: Running partition type [0] subtype [16] (offset 0x[00010000])
_PART[firmware]: Writing to partition subtype [17] at offset 0x310000

_MQTT[JOBS]: [150][_mqtt_jobs_stream_start] File ID: [0]
_MQTT[JOBS]: [151][_mqtt_jobs_stream_start] File size: [3466990]
_MQTT[JOBS]: [165][_mqtt_jobs_stream_start] Number of packets of [4]KB to download: [847]
_MQTT[JOBS]: [166][_mqtt_jobs_stream_start] Size of the last packet: [1774]

_MQTT[PUBSUB]: [684][_mqtt_publish] Publishing to topic :: 
[$aws/things/<serialNumber>/streams/<AFR_OTA_STREAMNAME>/get/json][82]. payload :: [{"c":"EMDV25ZNqewSnKgur3ATKR5Un6jTfz3","s":1,"f":0,"l":4096,"o":0}][66].
_MQTT[PUBSUB]: [400][_mqtt_handle_deserialized_info] Message from Topic: [$aws/things/<serialNumber>/streams/<AFR_OTA_STREAMNAME>/data/json][83] Payload [5531]
{"c":"EMDV25ZNqewSnKgur3ATKR5Un6jTfz3","f":0,"i":1,"l":4096,"p":"<PART_OF_THE_FILE>"}

_MQTT[PUBSUB]: [684][_mqtt_publish] Publishing to topic :: 
[$aws/things/<serialNumber>/streams/<AFR_OTA_STREAMNAME>/get/json][82]. payload :: [{"c":"BmC3wKLdhkmZmgNnsrKy1DooD03SJHW","s":1,"f":0,"l":4096,"o":0}][66].
_MQTT[PUBSUB]: [400][_mqtt_handle_deserialized_info] Message from Topic: [$aws/things/<serialNumber>/streams/<AFR_OTA_STREAMNAME>/data/json][83] Payload [5531]
{"c":"EMDV25ZNqewSnKgur3ATKR5Un6jTfz3","f":0,"i":2,"l":4096,"p":"<PART_OF_THE_FILE>"}
_MQTT_JSON[CALLBACK]: [442][json_aws_stream_data_accepted] clientToken invalid [BmC3wKLdhkmZmgNnsrKy1DooD03SJHW] :: [EMDV25ZNqewSnKgur3ATKR5Un6jTfz3]

_MQTT[PUBSUB]: [684][_mqtt_publish] Publishing to topic :: 
[$aws/things/<serialNumber>/streams/<AFR_OTA_STREAMNAME>/get/json][82]. payload :: [{"c":"Djam59mo56QXEKwYF0XGfYUbkBtu25e","s":1,"f":0,"l":4096,"o":0}][66].
coreMQTT: Unexpected packet type from server: PacketType=7b.

_MQTT[PUBSUB]: [684][_mqtt_publish] Publishing to topic :: 
[$aws/things/<serialNumber>/streams/<AFR_OTA_STREAMNAME>/get/json][82]. payload :: [{"c":"eIXW0dJE5alCR8JmjzEPJv8ixPmWreu","s":1,"f":0,"l":4096,"o":0}][66].
coreMQTT: Unexpected packet type from server: PacketType=7b
<infinite loop>

Questions:

Why do the responses not match the documentation, which indicates that the "clientToken" in the responses should correspond to the one in the payload ("c")?

Why is the order of the responses not following the offset specified in the payload?


